# Broken Closing Effect on Drawer Menu

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-animate, css-animations

There is a problem on my dropdown menu.

I want to open that dropdown right to left, and close it left to right with full height.

The problem is, the animation works while its opening. But it doesnt work while its closing. The drawer menu is closing any effect or animation.

And another weird thing is, when i inspect the code from browser, if i toggle the tick on "animation: transform-display .2s;", opening and closing animations are working properly.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIpPt.png): [image]

But, if i toggle "show" class from .cls parton brower which is toggles the drawer menu, closing animation doesnt work.

[image]

Can i get help?

This is HTML part.

```
 <div class="nav-first-right ml-auto navbar-icon-top navbar-expand-lg ">
        <ul class="navbar-nav  align-items-center ml-auto nav-first-ul">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow no-caret dropdown-user user-menu-li">
                    <button class="btn btn-icon btn-transparent-dark dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownUserImage"
                            href="javascript:void(0);" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                            aria-expanded="false"><img class="img-fluid" src="{{ user().profilePhoto }}"></button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right border-0 shadow"
                         aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownUserImage">
```

This is the CSS part.

```
    .nav-item .dropdown-menu {
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 2px 5px rgb(0 0 0 / 75%) !important;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    /*left: 0;*/
    right: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 0;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    
}

.nav-item .dropdown-menu.show { 
display: block;
    animation: transform-display .2s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-delay: 0ms;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
} 

.osahan-nav-top .nav-item .dropdown-menu:not(show) {

    animation: transform-display--reversed .2s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-delay: 0ms;
    animation-timing-function: linear
}

@keyframes transform-display {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes transform-display--reversed {
    0% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    }
    99% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this animation even without keyframes by just transition.
just assume before and after scenario for transition.

```
.dropdown-menu{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
}
.dropdown-menu.show{
    transform: translateX(0);
    visibility: visible;
    opacity:1;
}
```